# ssl chain order not correct

Tags: ssl, x509, pkix

Below is the order in the ssl on my server. In a ssl test i got the remark that the sequence is incorrect. What is the correct order?

```
Subject domain.eu
Valid from 29/Dec/2016 to 29/Dec/2017
Issuer  COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA

Subject AddTrust External CA Root
Valid from 30/May/2000 to 30/May/2020
Issuer  AddTrust External CA Root

Subject COMODO RSA Certification Authority
Valid from 30/May/2000 to 30/May/2020
Issuer  AddTrust External CA Root

Subject COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
Valid from 12/Feb/2014 to 11/Feb/2029
Issuer  COMODO RSA Certification Authority
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/), [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should match the issuer from the previous certificate with the subject from the next.